# Using OAuth 2.0 with angular 7

Tags: angular, oauth, angular7, fitbit

I am trying to use the FitBit Web API. Before accessing the API, I have to use the OAuth2.0 framework. So from the [FitBit API Documentation Page](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/oauth2/), there is an example that is:

```
https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=22942C&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffitbit_auth&scope=activity%20nutrition%20heartrate%20location%20nutrition%20profile%20settings%20sleep%20social%20weight
```

The first question is: Should I use GET or POST method? The information needed is located inside the URL created, so my intuition says I should use GET.

When using GET method, the response is weird. I expect some kinf of code so I can use in the next API call that will get the actual measurements. The call I am trying to make is:

```
this.http.get('https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/userID/activities/heart/date/today/1d.json')
```

but I do not know exactly how to use the token, the OAuth2.0 process does NOT return.

Sorry for the long question, but any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "When using GET method, the response is weird"

The response is HTML because you have made a GET request to their authentication portal. What you are supposed to do is actually redirect the user to the url:

```
https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=22942C&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ffitbit_auth&scope=activity%20nutrition%20heartrate%20location%20nutrition%20profile%20settings%20sleep%20social%20weight
```

...and then in the url replace the `redirect_uri` param with a link to your site (or localhost if you are in dev).

After the user has authenticated with Fitbit and allowed access to your app fitbit will redirect the user to the url provided along with an `access_token`. [See doc](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/oauth2/#access-token-request)

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0MzAzNDM3MzUsInNjb3BlcyI6Indwcm8gd2xvYyB3bnV0IHdzbGUgd3NldCB3aHIgd3dlaSB3YWN0IHdzb2MiLCJzdWIiOiJBQkNERUYiLCJhdWQiOiJJSktMTU4iLCJpc3MiOiJGaXRiaXQiLCJ0eXAiOiJhY2Nlc3NfdG9rZW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0MzAzNDAxMzV9.z0VHrIEzjsBnjiNMBey6wtu26yHTnSWz_qlqoEpUlpc",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "c643a63c072f0f05478e9d18b991db80ef6061e4f8e6c822d83fed53e5fafdd7",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "user_id": "26FWFL"
}
```

You can then use this access token to make future requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Zze. I am confused tho. At first, I will not make an http GET method, instead, I have to redirect the user to the link provided (with method `navigateByUrl()` located in '@anular/router' i suppose). Then after the user has authenticated I will have the access_token. So in order to get that data I have to use a POST method, where in the body, I will include the `access_token`? Is this correct?

Comment: @OrestisZekai What should happen is FitBit will redirect to the URL you provide in the initial redirect in `redirect_uri `. In your app, set up a page to handle this / await this response. They will hit your page with something like: `http://localhost:4200/FitBitRedirectURI?access_token=xxxx` then all you have to do is scrape that url param data out and you get the access token. From that point on, all future requests you will include this token.

Comment: I made it work, but thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @OrestisZekai Glad to hear it :)